# Creating indoor map in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, indoor

I'm trying to create an indoor map(from floor plan) in `GeoServer` and display in via `OpenLayers`.

The only way that I found is to create a `Store` in `GeoServer`(in my case, using `ImagePyramid`) from georeferenced `.tiff`, which one has a local bounding box(`[0, 0, 11, 9]` in `EPSG:3857`, in my case).

It works fine, but is there another way?

I'm looking to `custom CRS`, but I don't know whether it's worth the effort.

Comment: GeoServer is using local/engineering CRS is such cases. If you do not use any tailored local CRS for other purposes like having a common origin for many indoor maps I do not see any advantage in creating a custom CRS for GeoServer. However, without custom CRS you can't reproject to other coordinate systems like EPSG:4326 but I guess you do not want to do that.

Comment: Does this map need to be survey accurate or just for general reference?  Also, do you want users to just turn on or off the building plan image or have more interaction with the building info (e.g. having various layers to turn on or off, run queries, perform editing)?

Comment: @artwork21, map must be as precise as it possible(to mm). All user interaction will be with floor plan.

Answer (score 4):

A new projection was introduced in [GeoServer 2.2](http://blog.geoserver.org/2012/09/21/geoserver-2-2-released/) to handle exactly this kind of situation:

> Better support for un-referenced data with the new EPSG:40400 code
>   that identifies a coordinate system made up of a generic 2D Cartesian
>   plane.

Your data will be representated correctly, but it will not be possible to reference it relative to data in another projection.

Here is a link to more information in the [GeoTools user guide](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/crs.html#generic-2d) (used by GeoServer)

> formally intended for working with things like CAD drawings where the
>   results are measured in meters.

An easy way to remember the code is the "404" which is reminiscent of the http status code for page not found.

Comment: Looks like the right way. I'll try it in my project. Thanks!