# published raster with custom coordinate system to geoserver (comes in as EPSG 404000), but it won't overlay with other layers?

Tags: raster, geoserver, wms, epsg, epsg-40400

I have an ecw file that is an aerial photo in a custom coordinate system. When I publish to geoserver, it specifies the EPSG as 404000. It seems like this isn't actually storing the coordinate system definition. When I preview the layer I can't see the full extent. If I change the declared SRS to EPSG 3857, then when I preview I can see the full extent of the image, but still it won't overlay with other data. However, I can't see the data at all when I load into desktop GIS. I'm wondering if this is due to the size - it is 3GB. I'm new to geoserver so I'm sure I'm missing something- what needs to be done to be able to see this image in the correct loation and overlaid with other data in EPSG 3857, or any other system for that matter?

Comment: This does not answer your question -- but for performance purposes (especially with a 3gb file), you should reproject it to the projection that all other layers are using (so reproject it into 3857).  Unless you have a good caching setup, GeoServer will reproject your raster every time it is loaded, which is SLOWWW.  You wont have any problems after that (assuming a proper reprojection), but if there's some reason you need it in this projection, I'm sure an inquiry can be done into why the srs is not being defined correctly.

Comment: [See here for info](http://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/developers-corner-improving-geotoolsgeoserver-raster-reprojection-performance/)

Comment: If you load the data into a desktop GIS (which?), what CRS definition is assigned to the layer? Maybe related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154462/proper-way-to-create-indoor-map-in-geoserver/155612#155612

Comment: Or run a gdalinfo on top of it. But yes, it's likely due to the custom CRS.

Comment: @AndreaAime what do you mean when you say run a gdal on top of it? I added the custom CRS to the geoserver epsg.properties file, and now I can choose that as declared srs but it still reads in initially as 404000.

Comment: @AndreJ I've tried to read the wms in both qgis and arcgis and tried various CRS, all with same result - can't see it. But can see it when I click layer preview in the geoserver web interface.

Comment: @ThomasHorner unforunatley reprojection is not really an option.. the image is in ecw format, and we don't have a license to create new ecw files. If I reproject and save it out as geotiff (which I think is the only option in qgis?) it turns into a 100 GB file

Comment: I mean get GDAL and run gdalinfo <filename.ecw>

Comment: From the answer I linked: `Your data will be representated correctly, but it will not be possible to reference it relative to data in another projection.`